# Searching for a string containing emoji symbols in mysql returing empty results

Tags: php, mysql, emoji, utf8mb4

I stored some title names that have some

> text + Emoji symbols (example : Washington D.C. Vacation Travel GuidðŸ˜ƒ )

in my table. If i try to search such complete string the result returned is empty. is there any way to support emoji search in mysql

**My Query** :

`select * from comments where comment like '%GuidðŸ˜ƒ%'`

returns empty result

If i simply give

`select * from comments where comment like '%Washington%'`

the resultant rows are being displayed.

I also made sure that the charset is utfmb4

Comment: Maybe if you use FULL TEXT SEARCH?

Comment: Can you elaborate, Sorry i never used it before.

Comment: may be its space problem in the like statement(means the space between 'Hello' and ':-)') cross verify with table data...

Comment: Some are separated  with space and some are not!

Comment: What does the resulting row look like when you get the match? Does it contain the three-ascii-char sequence ":" + "-" + ")", or a multibyte smiley? MySQL doesn't convert strings to emoticons for you.

Comment: You can read more about `Full-text` in this document: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx
I can't guarantee that it's the solution for you, but in some cases it better than `LIKE %..`

Answer (score 0):

with respective to above comments modify your query like this and try

```
select * from comments where comment like '%Hello :-)%' OR '%Hello:-)%'
```